# wcout function does not print a french character

Tags: g++, wchar-t, c++

I am using the wcin in order to store a single character in a wchar_t. Then I try to print it with a wcout call and the french character 'é' : but I can't see it at my console.

My compiler is g++ 4.5.4 and my OS is Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits.

Here is my attempt (wideChars.cpp) :

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    wchar_t aChar;
    cout << "Enter your char : ";
    wcin >> aChar;
    wcout << L"You entered " << aChar << L" .\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I lauch the programm :

```
$ ./wideChars 
Enter your char : é
You entered  .
```

So, what's wrong with this code ?

Comment: What encoding is your terminal set to?

Comment: Hello, how can I check this ? Regards

Comment: I am retracting my answer. I have checked this on my own Xubuntu installation and I see the same problems. For whatever reason the `wcin` is refusing to read the 'é' character and it is setting the fail bit.

Comment: I think it is a compiler problem : as I replaced line 7 with wcout << "Enter your char (like é)"; and again I can't see the letter 'é' in the prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add some error checking. Test what does `wcin.good()` return after the input and what does `wcout.good()` return after the "You entered" print? I suspect one of those will return `false`.

What are your `LANG` and `LC_*` environment variables set to?

<strike>Then try to fix this by adding this at the top of your `main()`: `wcin.imbue(std::locale("")); wcout.imbue(std::locale(""));`</strike>

I do not have my Ubuntu at hand right now, so I am flying blind here and mostly guessing.

**UPDATE**

If the above suggestion does not help then try to construct locale like this and `imbue()` this locale instead.

```
std::locale loc (
    std::locale (),
    new std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>("")));
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what works for me. <strike>The key is to set the C locale as well. IMHO, this is a bug in GNU C++ standard library implementation. Unless I am mistaken, setting `std::locale::global("");` should also set the C library locale.</strike>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>

#define DUMP(x) do { std::wcerr << #x ": " << x << "\n"; } while (0)

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    std::locale loc ("");
    std::locale::global (loc);
    DUMP(std::setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL));
    DUMP(std::setlocale(LC_ALL, ""));    
    wcin.imbue (loc);

    DUMP (wcin.good());
    wchar_t aChar = 0;
    wcin >> aChar;
    DUMP (wcin.good());
    DUMP ((int)aChar);
    wcout << L"You entered " << aChar << L" .\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

I am confused, now I cannot reproduce it again and setting `std::locale::global(loc);` seems to do the right thing wrt/ the C locale as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answser : just after the input, wcin.good() returns me 0 (so, false), and just after the last output : wout.good() returns me 1 (so, true). My LANG env variable is set to fr_FR.UTF-8, and "echo $LC_*" gives me "escapeChars escapeChars.cpp limits limits.cpp wideChars wideChars.cpp". Now I'll try your next solutions. My source file and executables are wideChars.cpp and wideChars.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of your solution helped me. Even when I've made the local with call loc(locale, new codecvt_bytename). I've also included the locale definition, and kept the directive "using namespace std" in main(). Here is my latest source file : http://pastebin.com/ir56SKP0

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE: I have updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: You're right, setting the C++ locale *should* also set the C locale (at least, as long as the C++ locale you specify has a name; otherwise, the behavior with respect to the C locale is implementation-defined). Naturally, it doesn't work the other way. Setting the C locale has no effect on the C++ locale. If this is a bug in GNU, it may be worth filing.

Comment: @wilx Thank you very much. That solved my problem. However, I did not manage to solve the issue related to wcout (though I've called wcout.imbue(loc)) : the 'é' entered in a string given to wcout is not printed. Anyway, that should be another topic.